# Eigen::Quaternion FromTwoVectors() does not return a valid quaternion

Tags: c++, eigen

I have two vectors in 3D space and I'm trying to use the function of `Eigen::Quaternion FromTwoVectors()` to calculate the rotation between them. Despite the fact that there is no unique solution to this problem, I'm getting a quaternion with almost 4 zero values (probably just numerical errors) e.g.: `6.95251e-310, 6.90758e-310, 9.88131e-324, 6.90758e-310`. And this is certainly not a valid quaternion.

```
Eigen::Vector3d normal1;
Eigen::Vector3d normal2;
Eigen::Quaterniond quat;
quat.FromTwoVectors(normal1, normal2);
std::cout << quat.x() << quat.y() << quat.z() << quat.w() << std::endl;
```

Using the same vectors to compute AngleAxis and then converting to a quaternion gives valid values:

```
Eigen::Vector3d axis = normal1.cross(normal2);
axis.normalize()
double angle = acos(normal1.dot(normal2));
Eigen::AngleAxisd aa(angle,axis);
Eigen::Quaterniond quat(aa);
std::cout << quat.x() << quat.y() << quat.z() << quat.w() << std::endl;
```

`0.000407447, 0.00621866, 0.0035146, 0.999974`

What is going wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the documentation for `FromTwoVectors` https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1Quaternion.html#title13

`FromTwoVectors` appears to be a static method. So you need to look at the return value. You should get correct answer if you tried `Eigen::Quaterniond out = Eigen::Quaterniond::FromTwoVectors(normal1, normal2)`.

Comment: An alternative would be `quat.setFromTwoVectors(normal1, normal2);